# Installing Biopython: ImportError: No module named Bio

Tags: python, fedora, biopython, python-install

trying to install Biopython on Fedora 21, Python 2.7. I've done the following

```
[mike@localhost Downloads](17:32)$ sudo pip2.7 install biopython
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 7.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting biopython
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:79: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading biopython-1.65.tar.gz (12.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 12.6MB 33kB/s 
Installing collected packages: biopython
  Running setup.py install for biopython
Successfully installed biopython-1.65
```

And then

```
[mike@localhost Downloads](17:32)$ ipython
Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Mar  9 2015, 16:20:48) 

In [1]: import Bio
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a7440e1156be> in <module>()
----> 1 import Bio

ImportError: No module named Bio
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried installing biopython using

```
sudo easy_install -f http://biopython.org/DIST/ biopython
```

and it installed it into /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/biopython-1.65-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/. Didn't work.

Then I tried installing it using the same command, without the sudo:

```
easy_install -f http://biopython.org/DIST/ biopython
```

which installed it into /home/mike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/biopython-1.65-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg

**And that worked!** Both for ipython and python. But why did it work...?

Comment: You are using anaconda not what the package was installed for

Comment: To install it for the Anaconda interpreter, use `conda install ...` instead

Comment: It doesn't work from ordinary Python either.

Answer (score 2):

One should be very careful when using `pip` and the like that it is *the* `pip` which goes along with the supposed Python interpreter.

I see that you are trying to import `Bio` from the Python interpreter you get by typing `ipython`. You can make sure that you invoke the `pip` of exactly this interpreter like so:

```
sudo ipython -m pip install biopython
```

Note that the installation is not exclusive to **i**python. It *is* however exclusive to whatever Python installation ipython is installed on top of.

Answer (score 1):

It's not good practice to `sudo pip`, since it may install things under root permission, which is usually not granted to ordinary program.

The problem probably lies in library path. The most informative tools will be

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
```

and

```
which python
pip --version
```

And use `pip install biopython --user` to replace `sudo pip`